# React: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am having the following code that gives me an error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and it points to the first row of the file: import React, {createContext} from 'react';

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext({
   isLoggedIn: false,
   UID: '',
   setUID: () => {},
   login: () => {},
   logout: () => {}
});

export default UserContext;
```

I have tried to add "type": "module" to my package.json but it causes a new error "ReferenceError: require is not defined" that points to my app.js file to the row "const express = require('express')". I have also tried to change the file name from UserContext.js to UserContext.mjs but it didn't solve the problem. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Use this `import {React, createContext} from 'react';`

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the same error

Comment: This should seal the deal
import * as React from 'react'


const UserContext = React.createContext({
   isLoggedIn: false,
   UID: '',
   setUID: () => {},
   login: () => {},
   logout: () => {}
});

export default UserContext;

Comment: This didn't work either, the problem seems to be the word "import" but I don't understand why because every other files that I have, have this kind of import React and they work well

Comment: Can you make a replica of any other working file and put your code underneath the import statement. Try it that way then

Comment: I have read that discussion and tried those things but nothing worked :(

Comment: You have already imported createContext, so no need to write React. createContext.  Simply write const UserContext = createContext({ .. });

Comment: I tried that now but then I get the error Unexpected token 'export' and it points to the last row "export default UserContext;"